Explain GUARANTEED MINIMUM CASH SURRENDER VALUE in an annuity in the US
I have a multi-year guaranteed annuity at a fixed rate of interest.  I am allowed to withdraw the full value at three years without a surrender charge.
The annuity includes the statement:
GUARANTEED MINIMUM CASH SURRENDER VALUE
The Guaranteed Minimum Cash Surrender Value equals 87.5% of the premium paid accumulated at the Nonforfeiture Interest Rate, less any prior partial surrenders and related surrender charges accumulated at the Nonforfeiture Interest Rate, less $50 per year accumulated at the Nonforfeiture Interest Rate, and less deductions for any required taxes, accumulated at the Nonforfeiture Interest Rate. All of the above are accumulated to the date of surrender.
The Nonforfeiture Interest Rate is lower than the fixed rate.  And there are no fees at any point in the annuity.
What does the GUARANTEED MINIMUM CASH SURRENDER VALUE mean.  When would it be applied?

I am far from sure, but at a guess:
Some annuities permit ending the agreement and withdrawing the balance again if you think you can get a better offer elsewhere. Of course, this may be less money than you put in, if the investments the annuity managers made are not doing well. What is being promised, I believe, is that if you do so you will be able to get back at least 87.5% of the annuity's nominal value minus the costs they mention.
As with the annuity itself, you are paying them to assume some of the risk of a severe market dip.
